# Why does the ObservableCollection<T> have two collection constructors?

Tags: c#

The [ObservableCollection(T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604) class has two constructors in which a collection of items can be passed. One constructor accepts an `IEnumerable(T)`, and the other a `List(T)`.

Given that `List(T)` implements `IEnumerable(T)`, why does the second constructor exist?

Comment: It maybe an optimization in the constructor for the case of passing a `List<T>`

Comment: Indeed - although that could easily have been implemented as a check within the `IEnumerable<T>` signature.

Comment: Looks like the `List` constructor existed before the `IEnumerable`

Comment: @JonSkeet: It looks like the difference is in how it calls the base constructor so I don't *think* you could achieve that unless you had two separate constructors.

Comment: @MattBurland: Nah, that could be done - both could call the `Collection(IList<T>)` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor that takes a `List` was introduced in .NET 3.0, while the one that takes an `IEnumerable` was not introduced until .NET 3.5, so removing the `List` constructor would have been a braking change.

My guess it they wrote it to take a `List`, shipped it, then later realized that it could be more general.

The [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,f63ea2601f5edbbb) has an interesting comment as well (not sure if it's pertinent):

```
    public ObservableCollection(List<T> list)
        : base((list != null) ? new List<T>(list.Count) : list)
    {
        // Workaround for VSWhidbey bug 562681 (tracked by Windows bug 1369339).
        // We should be able to simply call the base(list) ctor.  But Collection<T>
        // doesn't copy the list (contrary to the documentation) - it uses the
        // list directly as its storage.  So we do the copying here.
        // 
        CopyFrom(list);
    }

    public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

        CopyFrom(collection);
    }
```

Comment: I've chosen as the answer over @MattBurland's answer as I assume backwards compatibility was the main reason for this (instead of performance).

Comment: Hmmm - that's not what https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169 says. That shows the `IEnumerable<T>` one being available in .NET 3.0. (I looked for exactly this change...)

Comment: Although https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737(v=vs.85).aspx agrees with you - looks like the version documentation is borked.

Comment: FWIW: I just started a project, targeted .NET 3.0 and if I try to create an `ObservableCollection` intellisense shows *both* constructors.

Comment: @JonSkeet I saw that too - I assumed the "Version Information" was wrong.  [The .NET 3.0 Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms658737(v=vs.85).aspx) does not show an overload that takes an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: The more I dig into this, the more I think it's the documentation that is incorrect. So it's not a backwards compatibility thing at all.

Comment: Perhaps their comment of "(contrary to the documentation)" applies to more things than just the implementation of the constructors, haha. However, if both constructors existed in the first place then I'm back to square one on why they were both created.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the source here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,f63ea2601f5edbbb

Without digging too deep, you'll notice this:

```
public ObservableCollection(List<T> list)
    : base((list != null) ? new List<T>(list.Count) : list)
{
    // Workaround for VSWhidbey bug 562681 (tracked by Windows bug 1369339).
    // We should be able to simply call the base(list) ctor.  But Collection<T>
    // doesn't copy the list (contrary to the documentation) - it uses the
    // list directly as its storage.  So we do the copying here.
    // 
    CopyFrom(list);
}
```

And this:

```
public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

    CopyFrom(collection);
}
```

Notice in the case of passing a `List<T>` it calls the base constructor with a new `List<T>` with it's capacity already set to match the `Count` of the list you passed in. Obviously you can't do this with an `IEnumerable<T>` because `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a `Count` property. So it looks like an optimization. If you already know how big the collection is going to be, you can avoid the penalty due to resizing the internal `List<T>` when you copy the source to it.

**Edit:** Also @DStanley's point about breaking changes. Which is probably more important anyway. **Edit again:** Or maybe not, since there seems to be some confusion about the documentation. But I created a project targeting .NET 3.0 and it appears that both constructors are there. If I use "Go to definition" in Visual Studio I can see this:

```
#region Assembly WindowsBase.dll, v3.0.0.0
// C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\WindowsBase.dll
#endregion

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection();   
        public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection);
        public ObservableCollection(List<T> list);
        //....
```

And this code, in .NET 3.0 compiles fine:

```
var list = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
IEnumerable<int> enumerable = (IEnumerable<int>)list;
var obsWithList = new ObservableCollection<int>(list);
var obsWithEnumerable = new ObservableCollection<int>(enumerable);
```

And with a little reflection:

```
var internalListProp = typeof(ObservableCollection<int>).GetProperty("Items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var l0 = (internalListProp.GetValue(obsWithList, null) as List<int>).Capacity;        // 3
var l1 = (internalListProp.GetValue(obsWithEnumerable, null) as List<int>).Capacity;  // 4
```

You can see that the capacity of the internal list is set to match the `Count` when a `List<T>` is passed in, but not when an `IEnumerable<T>` is passed.