# Duplicate constructor in ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, constructor, .net-7.0

In System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection there are among other things these two constructors:

```
public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(new List<T>(collection ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection))))
{
}

public ObservableCollection(List<T> list) : base(new List<T>(list ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list))))
{
}
```

Why does the List one exist? Shouldn't IEnumerable be enough in the first place? I checked and both use the same new List constructor so there shouldn't be any optimization going on but I am not sure.

Edit: The existing answer [Why does the ObservableCollection<T> have two collection constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438534/why-does-the-observablecollectiont-have-two-collection-constructors)
Only applies to .Net Framework, in .Net 7 which I am referring to the workaround does not exist, so the List constructor seems completely redundant.